# Add background color of GridView column header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am using `OnRowDataBound` method to set the color of some cells background.

Refer below code for `OnRowDataBound` method :

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    e.Row.Cells(0).CssClass = ""
End If
```

Above code will change the background color of 1st row in the table. How do I set the color of Column header? Since I am not using `BoundField` in ASP.Net so I can't set the `HeaderStyle-CssClass`

I am referring to this site http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/01/convert-gridview-columns-to-rows-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `DataControlRowType.Header` for that.

```
If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header) Then
    'set a class for the entire row
    e.Row.CssClass = "HeaderRow"

    'or define a color for the entire row
    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red
End If
```

But you can also set the CSS class for the header in other places.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderRow">
```

Or

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderRow">
```

Comment: Working exactly like what I want. Thank you.

Comment: Another one is, how do I make center the Header Text? I tried adding `e.Row.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center` but it's not working.